# where can i find feedparser documentation?

Tags: rss, feedparser

feedparser documentation used to be available on http://feedparser.org/ but the URL now says the resource cannot be found and there is no forwarding address.

Anyone know where the documentation has moved or where I can find the documentation?

Also, using feedparser how can I retrieve an attribute for a tag. For example if a feed has a

```
<author firstName="john" lastName="doe">,
```

how can I retrieve the first and last names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others added, the material is now back up in a more official location:  http://packages.python.org/feedparser/

Original Answer:
The wayback machine is your friend!  To make a long story short, the author took all his material off the web.  But you can find the doc's at http://web.archive.org/web/20110726051510/http://feedparser.org/docs/

Comment: Relevant issue for the current Feedparser maintainers: https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/issues/detail?id=305

Comment: downgraded this because the documentation at  http://packages.python.org/feedparser/is more up to date

Answer (score 2):

The documentation used to be down. It's back up: http://packages.python.org/feedparser/